Эмодзи в ckeditor5 django, как подключить?
Я установил на сайте (Django) редактор ckeditor5, однако нигде не могу найти как можно прикрутить к нему использование эмоджи. Причем, если я скопирую текст с какого-нибудь ресурса, где эти эмоджи есть и вставлю текст в поле ввода текста, то все эмоджи будут видны, но после сохранения текста, сохранится только та часть текста, которая была ДО первой эмоджи в тексте.
Как можно установить плагин (или вручную) в редактор, да еще и так, чтобы было много популярных эмоджи (как в телеграм или вотсапп)?

Это проблема не в Django, а в MySQL-базе, которую необходимо преобразовать из кодировки utf8 в utf8mb4

Ну и вы смешали два вопроса в одном: даже если вы установите плагин с популярными эмоджи — они точно так же продолжат пропадать после сохранения, пока вы не исправите кодировку

Спасибо за подсказку, поправил кодировку БД на utf8mb4_unicode_ci, теперь вместо эмодзи и иконок отображаются ??? - это уже что-то. Но вопрос об использовании эмодзи все равно надо как-то решать, т.к. бывает необходимость их использовать, получается, что при копировании ckeditor5 их видит, но почему же сохранить правильно не может?

Кодировку mysql-клиента на стороне Django тоже не забывайте поправлять

andreymal в settings.py надо это делать?

Все же, что касается настройки работы с эмодзи, есть ли какой-нибудь опыт, я не смог ничего дельного найти.
